# How can I test OS updates involving drivers before applying them?

Tags: windows, mac, drivers, updates

I think we can assume that driver, or firmware for a mac, problems make up a great deal of headache, especially during OS updates/upgrades. But sometimes it's not easy to recover from them or it might even be fatal to the computer hardware (google something like `windows update breaks drivers` or `mac update destroys hardware` if you don't believe me). And I don't want to go through the trauma of System Restore/Time Machine/rolling back drivers every time a driver fails (below I'll explain why these might not even work sometimes).

---

I made a diagram of the whole process so it's easier to understand. [image: link]

Basically, The **red** arrow represents you installing a windows/mac update/upgrade and the **blue** arrow represents immediately (say a week) after the update/upgrade, assuming it succeeded (more on that below). The "computer fan" represents a slaughterhouse of driver problems at update/upgrade time. You generally pass through it **twice** per update/upgrade as described by the arrows;
The whole process really doesn't have anything to do with the physical fan in a PC (unless *its* drivers are involved).

*For PCs:* (the following is irrelevant for Macs) Please don't mistake **updates** (which come from Microsoft/Apple) for **driver updates** (download from hardware vendors). I never needed to do a driver update and I'm sure most people won't have to.

---

There are two kinds of driver problems people experience at the "computer fan":

1. The ones where the OS can't use the hardware, which is otherwise working fine e.g. `Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade breaking webcams` - these can be fixed later by the above utilities.
2. The ones where the problem is actually destroying the affected hardware e.g. `Bootcamp in 2016 MBP blowing internal speakers` (*See end of question*) - these cannot be fixed by the above utilities later.

While you can contact (chat/call/email/Genius Bar) tech support and they could fix these for you, it won't be your best solution if your warranty expired (and this doesn't even prevent the problem in the first place). So what I - and probably a lot of other people - need is a way to test these updates/upgrades before I actually install them, so I can hold back the update/upgrade until it gets patched.

---

- First I was thinking a VM (any hypervisor which lets me take snapshots) could solve No. 1 for me but I later read in the Parallels forum that it uses different EFI/BIOS in the guest than in the host. I couldn't find info about VMware/VBox/Hyper-V but I think they also work like that, correct me if I'm wrong.

This means driver differences (even on Apple hardware which is very surprising for an OSX guest). So it's not very reliable, No. 1 problems might happen on the host (my computer) but go undetected in the guest. And forget testing No. 2 on VMs because it's not really a test when you're using the same hardware!

- Another option (that could also test No. 2) is to buy a spare machine of the *same* model (and also includes By-the-order configurations on your PC/Mac). This is the most stable option (but I can't do snapshots on a physical computer) but the only major problem is such a layout is *terribly expensive* for someone who's planning to use it for a couple years (think 4-7), plus your model might be out of stock (which means waiting, possibly for a long time) or not manufactured anymore (i.e. this option is impossible).

And you might even need *multiple* of these spares for cases where a driver problem actually blew the hardware of the first spare. This option is actually a waste of money for people who upgrade to every new model/generation! (but I don't)

- The last option (and fairly modest, may also handle No. 2) I can think of is browsing the forums at the userbase, where you look for other users with your hardware report driver problems with updates/upgrades. This may be a litter harder for PCs than Macs because of the multitude of models out there, but to reduce volume you can regard your entire model line as relevant, which is a little more dicey as you're now comparing red apples to green apples but it's better than nothing.

  ---

Now the question remains:

## Which of these can test updates/upgrades involving drivers before I actually update?

Feel free to suggest options I might have missed. Assume a Mac (optionally with  a bootcamp setup), or PC single-booting Windows (No. 1 in Linux is widespread anyway, so I don't care about those)

*Note:* Technically windows on bootcamp is neither an update nor upgrade, but here I regard it as an *upgrade* in the sense you configure the installation options.

Comment: This is a very broad question that will have many possible and possibly correct answer. These characteristics make it a poor fit for SuperUser, which is about specific questions with one specific correct answer. You will likely get a much better solution posting this in a forum where open discussion is encouraged and many possible solutions can be suggested and discussed.

Comment: All that said, if you only have one physical computer, the best way to test major updates is to run them in a virtual machine. The drawbacks for this are that the virtual machine will have different (virtual) hardware and you will not be running it in the same way.

Comment: Well actually (scouring the internet for a couple days), I'm not even sure if there _is_ an answer to this question but anyway, I narrowed the basic question, does it help? (Sorry for having you misunderstand the question, I'm trying to test drivers so a VM won't help like I explained above)

Comment: If drivers are what you need tested then you'll need to dual-boot, which means two (or more) OS instances running on the same physical hardware (no virtualization). This isn't particularly hard and the technologies for dual-booting are decently mature and well supported.

Comment: Note that for Mac it's not always that simple, but .. Clone boot drive, upgrade one copy, test, clone back if you don't like it. Time Machine will **not** allow you to go downhill, so you must swap out your TM drive before you do this. The other caveat is that Apple can put firmware upgrades into OS upgrades which can make it impossible to go backwards. It would be very unusual for that to include merely the 2nd most recent OS, Sierra back to El Cap etc, but Lion & Mountain Lion have been knocked out of that downgrade path recently.